# Responsive Embed YouTube Customized Size Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, embed

I understand Bootstrap 3.3.6 has support for 16by9 and 4by3 formats for embedded iframes. How do I embed if I would like to du a customized own size that is something other than 16by9 and 4by3? Like a format of 5by3 but still remain proportionate when scaling.

Thank you very much.

The Bootstrap suggested ways:

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`embed-responsive-XbyY` only gives the padding bottom equal to ratio Y/X as percentage

You can easily make an `embed-responsive-5by3` 3/5 = 60%

```
.embed-responsive-5by3{
   padding-bottom: 60%;
}
```

`.embed-responsive` gives the rest of the styling

Comment: Thank you very much